# Processing massive amounts of data with CronJob

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron that needs to run, basically it will generate a  PDF file with mPDF and send it to the people specified,The amount of emails this cron will handle can be anything from 1 person to 1000 people and possibly more.

The Generating process already takes quite a bit of time as the cron needs to access the database and prepare the PDF file.

At the moment, when the cron reaches the 10th client it bombs out, because the memory limit is reached.(It takes a lot of memory)

Is there anyway to run the cron and have it free up the memory as it goes, or even have it run without a memory limit? Any possible solutions...

**Code**

```
$table = "tblclients";
$fields = "id";
$where = array("status" => "Active");
$clientsresult = select_query($table,$fields,$where);
while ($clientsdata = mysql_fetch_array($clientsresult)){
   $client_id=$clientsdata['id'];
   $period_from=date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d").' -0 years -1 months -0 days'));
   $period_to=date(sprintf("%02d", $day).'-m-Y');
   if(get_balance_for_period($client_id,-2000,29)>0){
      $statement=generate_custom_report($client_id,$period_from,$period_to,"F");
      mail_statment($client_id,MYROOT.'/generated/'.$statement,$period_from,$period_to);
      unlink(MYROOT.'/generated/'.$statement);
   }
}
```

The below code shows how the cron is run, `generate_custom_report` generates the report, which is then sent using the `mail_statement` function and the pdf is then deleted...

I am not sure where memory would be kept, because the same variables are used in each look, is the memory not freed?

**Memory Usage:**

In the below example you should be able to see how the memory is used with each client. You will notice there are only 25 clients processed here. But the memory usage was 600MB... meaning if you process lets say 1000 you will end up needing 24GB of memory, which most servers will not provide...

Is there a possible solution to the memory abuse?

```
sending to 1 | Memory bytes: 16123384
sending to 12 | Memory bytes: 56914024
sending to 13 | Memory bytes: 79047568
sending to 14 | Memory bytes: 111560288
sending to 17 | Memory bytes: 222810720
sending to 23 | Memory bytes: 250151664
sending to 24 | Memory bytes: 293685600
sending to 33 | Memory bytes: 299987024
sending to 30 | Memory bytes: 313091856
sending to 34 | Memory bytes: 386661752
sending to 41 | Memory bytes: 411917048
sending to 52 | Memory bytes: 446857024
sending to 65 | Memory bytes: 457177864
sending to 59 | Memory bytes: 464880584
sending to 63 | Memory bytes: 498235608
sending to 97 | Memory bytes: 526843496
sending to 83 | Memory bytes: 534199208
sending to 86 | Memory bytes: 546184000
sending to 85 | Memory bytes: 556632648
sending to 88 | Memory bytes: 567034592
sending to 89 | Memory bytes: 576347920
sending to 94 | Memory bytes: 589466432
sending to 93 | Memory bytes: 598519680
sending to 96 | Memory bytes: 602776992
sending to 102 | Memory bytes: 604044912
```

Comment: In general: sure, you can do that. You just need to code your script in a way that it doesn't try to keep too much stuff in memory (data in variables) at once. If you're unlucky and mPDF is coded shoddily so *it* won't free memory, you may have some problems. Of course, we have no idea about any of this without seeing what you're doing exactly.

Comment: Hi @deceze please check the update

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines in the PHP file and let me know if it works.

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "0");
ini_set("memory_limit","2048M"); // change it as required
```

Comment: The thing is, I do not know what the memory used will be. On my system it ran 2GB of memory with 80 clients. But on other systems it (depending on the client profile, the memory needed may be more)

Comment: @Marcel setting the `memory_limit` to `-1` will "remove" the memory_limit.

Comment: set memory_limit to -1(unlimited). will that work?? Don't know if it is good to set it to -1